# ServiceStack: Accessing the IRequest in the Service returns null

Tags: servicestack

I am using [Servicestack](https://servicestack.net/). I have a base class for my Services, like so:

```
public abstract class ServiceHandlerBase : Service
```

and then some methods and properties in there of interest. I already have several methods that accesses the IRequest object, like:

```
    protected AlfaOnline GetContactItem()
    {
        string deviceUUID = Request.Headers.Get(Constants.DEVICE_UUID); // <-- calling this method from constructor will give NullRef on Request here
        string authToken = Request.Headers.Get(Constants.AUTH_TOKEN);
        // do stuff
        return existingContactItem;
    }
```

which works well inside my service implementations, no problems there.

Now, I wanted to use this exact same method *directly from the base class*, calling it in the constructor:

```
    public ServiceHandlerBase()
    {
        AlfaOnline ao = GetContactItem();
    }
```

but I then get a `NullReferenceException` on the `Request` object as noted above.

When is the Request object ready to access and use? Because it's not null inside the service implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access any dependencies like `IRequest` in the constructor before they've been injected, they're only accessible after the `Service` class has been initialized like when your Service method is called.

You can use a [Custom Service Runner](http://docs.servicestack.net/api-design#custom-hooks) to execute custom logic before any Service is Executed, e.g:

```
public class MyServiceRunner<T> : ServiceRunner<T> 
{
    public override void OnBeforeExecute(IRequest req, TRequest requestDto) {
      // Called just before any Action is executed
    }
}
```

And register it with ServiceStack in your AppHost with:

```
public override IServiceRunner<TRequest> CreateServiceRunner<TRequest>(ActionContext ctx)
{           
    return new MyServiceRunner<TRequest>(this, ctx);
}
```

But if you just want to run some logic for a Service class you can now override `OnBeforeExecute()` in your base class, e.g:

```
public abstract class ServiceHandlerBase : Service
{
    public override void OnBeforeExecute(object requestDto)
    {
        AlfaOnline ao = GetContactItem();
    }
}
```

See [ServiceFilterTests.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Tests/ServiceFilterTests.cs) for a working example.

If you're implementing `IService` instead of inheriting the `Service` base class you can implement [IServiceBeforeFilter](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/9e26565bc44928f674d5048b8abbdaafc22bff9e/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/IService.cs#L11) instead.

The new Service Filters is available from v5.4.1 that's now [available on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

Comment: ok, I didnt find any method to override, that also is called always (like the constructor).Point is, I want some code to be executed everytime. I thought about putting it in the `GlobalRequestFilters` or `PreRequestFilters`, but I dont think its a good fit there. I have different base classes depending on what "service" it is, so, `GlobalRequestFilters` is too general. Wouldnt it be good to have like `AfterServiceCreated` method to override, that is executed before the Service method?

Comment: @Ted Services doesn't have any base classes or overridable methods by design, you can use a [Custom Service Runner](http://docs.servicestack.net/api-design#custom-hooks) to apply custom logic around.

Comment: @Ted FYI I've updated my answer to include the new Service filters you can use instead of creating a Service runner.

Comment: Hey Mythz, you just added that override? =)

Comment: I get some Exceptions after upgrade, described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54850801/servicestack-upgrade-to-5-4-1-gives-me-reflectiontypeloadexception-on-servicest Thanks =)

Comment: And also this, I just noticed:  `Method not found: 'ServiceStack.IO.FileSystemVirtualFiles `

Comment: @Ted just need to [clear your NuGet packages](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget#redownloading-myget-packages) if you have any issues with the pre release packages on MyGet

Comment: Ok, I'll try to remember that =)