# ServiceStack: Upgrade to 5.4.1 gives me ReflectionTypeLoadException on ServiceStack.Common

Tags: servicestack

I was running ServiceStack 5.2.0, until I upgraded due [to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54840831/servicestack-accessing-the-irequest-in-the-service-returns-null).

After doing that, and running the application again, I now get `ReflectionTypeLoadException`, when processing the Assembly `ServiceStack.Common, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=02c12cbda47e6587`.

In my code, for some reason irrelevant to this question, I do the following:

```
Type[] typeArray = assembly.GetTypes();
```

and when I do, I get this error:

[image]

> {"Method 'GetKeyValuePairs' in type 'ServiceStack.SimpleAppSettings' from assembly 'ServiceStack.Common, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=02c12cbda47e6587' does not have an implementation.":"ServiceStack.SimpleAppSettings"}

I thought "let's avoid processing Servicestack, as it's not really what I'm after anyway here", so I changed it to:

```
if (!assembly.DefinedTypes.Any(x => x.FullName.StartsWith("SomeThing")))
```

but I still get the same error when execution hits this line.

### Update

After upgrading, I actually see LoaderExceptions elsewhere too:

> System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or
> more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property
> for more information.    at
> System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)    at
> System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes()    at
> System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()    at
> tWorks.Core.CoreServerCommons.RequestProcessing.RequestProcessorFactory`2.<>c.b__8_0(Assembly
> assembly) in
> ....RequestProcessorFactory.cs:line
> 105

Has something happened to some underlying library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mythz said in the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54840831/servicestack-accessing-the-irequest-in-the-service-returns-null), all that was needed to do, was to clear the NuGet cache:

`VS --> Tools --> NuGet Packet Manager --> Packet Manager Settings --> Clear All NuGet Caches(s)`